# Showing the selected value in Drop down select using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to load a drop down option values based on database information. I have the following code and its working fine but I don't know how to code in the following to show the selected value.

```
$output = null;

foreach ($records->result() as $row) {
    $output .= "<option value='".$row->sub_category_id."'>".$row->sub_category_name."</option>";
}
return $output;
```

I know I should be using something like following, but I can't understand how to put the following code together with the above codes.

```
 if ($row->sub_category_id == $sub_category_id) {select="selected"}
```

Could you please show me?
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost finished it correctly. here you go:

```
$output = null;

foreach ($records->result() as $row){
   $selected="";
   if($row->sub_category_id==$sub_category_id) $selected="selected";
   $output .= "<option $selected value='".$row->sub_category_id."'>".$row->sub_category_name."</option>";

}
return $output;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to make a slight change in your code and now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator:

```
foreach ($records->result() as $row){



 $output .= "<option value='".$row->sub_category_id."' " .$row->sub_category_id==$sub_category_id ? 'selected="selected"':''+ ">".$row->sub_category_name."</option>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a selected value:

```
$selectedValue = 1; // Selected value in dropdown.

foreach ($records->result() as $row){
  $output .= "<option value='".$row->sub_category_id."'".($row->sub_category_id == $selectedValue ? " selected" : "").">".$row->sub_category_name."</option>";
}
return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it nicely, where "$sub_category_id" is the id of the currently selected option

```
$sub_category_id = 1; //Selected ID
$output = "<select>";
foreach ($records->result() as $row){
    $selected = "";
    if ($sub_category_id == $row->sub_category_id) {
        $selected = "selected='selected'";
    }
    $output .= "<option value='{$row->sub_category_id}' {$selected}>{$row->sub_category_name}</option>";
}
$output .= "</select>";
```